# spring rest: uploading large files (1GB) via rest controller

Tags: java, spring, rest, multipartform-data

*[context: java 8, spring boot 1.5.1]*

We are creating a RESTful service where we need to be able to upload large files. What I want is an api that would look something like this

```
@RequestLine("POST /object")
@Headers("Content-Type: multipart/form-data")
void create(InputStreamResource resource, ...);
```

I don't want to use a `MultipartFile` as the entire file would be read, nor an `HttpServletRequest` as that doesn't seem to belong here but rather begs the need for a `HttpMessageConverter` of sorts. Having said that, with an `HttpServletRequest` I could solve the problem as follows

```
ServletFileUpload upload = new ServletFileUpload();
FileItemIterator iterator = upload.getItemIterator(request);
while (iterator.hasNext()) {
  FileItemStream e = iterator.next();
  if (!e.isFormField()) {
    InputStream inputStream = item.openStream();
    //...
  }
}
```

Ideally I would like an `InputStream` or something that wraps one, e.g. `InputStreamResource`(as shown above).

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I got it working in this way and it seems the only way to handle upload without temp file or reading the file into byte array using @RequestBody annotation, as was suggested on stackoverflow.com in one thread:

```
@RequestMapping("firmware/{firmwareId:\\d+}/logs/upload")
public
@ResponseBody
ResponseEntity handleUploadLogs(@PathVariable("firmwareId") final Long firmwareId, final HttpServletRequest request) {
    try (final InputStream is = getInputStream(request)) {
        if (is != null) {
            firmwareContentService.uploadLogs(firmwareId, is);

            return ok().build();
        } else {
            return badRequest().build();
        }
    } catch (IOException | FileUploadException e) {
        return badRequest().build();
    }
}

private InputStream getInputStream(final HttpServletRequest request) throws IOException, FileUploadException {
    final ServletFileUpload upload = new ServletFileUpload();
    final FileItemIterator iterator = upload.getItemIterator(request);

    InputStream is = null;

    while (iterator.hasNext()) {
        final FileItemStream item = iterator.next();

        if (!item.isFormField()) {
            is = item.openStream();

            break;
        }
    }

    return is;
}
```

<strike>**UPDATE**</strike>

This simple code worked for me as well. Just put InputStream into method parameters:

```
@PostMapping("firmware/{firmwareId:\\d+}/logs/upload")
public
@ResponseBody
ResponseEntity handleUploadLogs(@PathVariable("firmwareId") final Long firmwareId, final InputStream is) {
    try {
        firmwareContentService.uploadLogs(firmwareId, is);

        return ok().build();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        return badRequest().build();
    }
}
```

The "simple code" above is not actually working. InputStream in method parameter contains whole http request.

Comment: Thanks, Igor. Unfortunately your solution I had already described in my original post (my apologies if it wasn't clear). The crux of my post was that I did **not** want an `HttpServletRequest` (or `MultipartFile` for that matter),  e.g. `ResponseEntity<Void> handleUploadLogs(final HttpServletRequest request)`, since I want a clean API and would be prefer to have a `InputStream` or a POJO which wraps one.

Comment: For example - if we take the reciprocal case, downloading a file - I don't don't need to pass an `HttpServletResponse` in order to write to its OutputStream, I need merely return a `ResponseEntity<Resource>` in order to stream the requested object.

Comment: Just put InputStream into method parameters. Somehow it worked for me.

Comment: Thanks, Igor - works like a charm. Thought you needed to use a `Resource` wrapper but that wasn't necessary - `void create(InputStream in, ...)` was all I needed to do.

Comment: I would appreciate if you accept my answer. Cheers!

Comment: Sorry Igor,  had to do more testing before I could accept and now it seems I spoke too soon :( ... the contents of the InputStream [A] spring passes in on the method call is not the same as if you read the file yourself using the java APIs [B]. An example would be to take a small image, read both streams [A & B] ]into byte array and compare the contents. Furthermore, when I save the contents [A] to disk, I was unable to open it as an image file. Do you follow?

Comment: (seems as if the InputStream contains the entire contents of the request, i.e. the raw multiparts)

Comment: Same here, unfortunately.

Comment: Are you importing statics for badRequest.build() and ok.build()? If so, is that code you can share?

Comment: it's

import static org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity.badRequest;
import static org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity.ok;